# How to force synchronous execution of getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

For a school history project, I'm making a timeline webpage ([live here](http://katavie.github.io/euro-timeline/)). To avoid having to repeatedly type the details for each, I put them in a spreadsheet and exported it as [JSON](http://katavie.github.io/euro-timeline/data.js).

In the nav, I created links labelled with the year of the event using Javascript.

I want to then use slick.js, a jQuery plugin, to turn the nav into a carousel, as demonstrated an the /slick-test-static.html of the live website linked above.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON("data.js", function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
          var string = JSON.stringify(result[i]);
          var parsed = JSON.parse(string);

          $('.slider').append("<li><a href=\"#" + parsed.number + "\">" + parsed.year + "</a></li>");
        }
      });

      $('.slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 8,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000
      });
    });
```

The links are created, but the slider isn't. I made a page where the links are created *not* using JSON, and it worked fine.

I think the problem is because the getJSON method is asynchronous, so the browser tries to create the slider before any items are even added to the slider. First, *is* this the problem? If so, what's the best way to fix it?

Comment: You can't do that.  You should use promises.

Comment: Instead of trying to block the UI, try to invoke slick asynchronously after the JSON is downloaded. Simply put its invocation inside the callback, after that loop.

Comment: @Bergi That worked, thanks! For some reason I overlooked the fact that I could do that.

Comment: You could do it using `$.ajaxSetup()` to set default options for all jQuery AJAX calls. But I'm not going to post it as an answer because what you're doing is wrong. Synchronous AJAX is deprecated, you should learn how to write proper async code.

Comment: @Barmar Any resources for learning to write "proper async code"?

Comment: Google "javascript async tutorial" finds a bunch of resources. I can't attest to their quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make this synchronous. With ES6 you can "fake" waiting on asynchronous actions using `async` and `await` but what it's doing is essentially the same as what you need to do to make this work.

You need to stick your `$('.slider').slick(...` code inside of the `$.getJSON` callback. You should not initialize the slider until the async callback is made.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps for your concrete question, but you can indeed make synchronous JSON requests.

The asynchronous request would be (in vanilla JS):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/bar/foo.txt", true); // Note the `true` here.
request.send(null);                       // When set to true, the request
                                         // will be asynchronous.
if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log("ok");
}
```

While the synchronous request would be:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log("ok");
}
```

You have some documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests